# use <form:input in dynamically added rows in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, spring-mvc, dynamic-html

I have created dynamic row(using javascript) in my JSP page. Now i want to use Spring Component `<form:input`

For spring component `<form:input` in  HTML, i have used

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
```

`<form:input path="hello" cssClass="textbox_Blue" maxlength='10' size='30' />`

now i want to know how to do it in java script.

Hopes the question is clear and informative.

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: @Mahesh.D sry i did smthing wrng...
hopes, nw the question is clear

Comment: All the spring code that you write in jsp, would be changed to html when you view your page. Checkout the html of that element using a tool like firebug and append that in your <form tag.

Comment: @Ankit thanks fr ur reply..........
Since all the Spring code is getting converted into Html, so firebug is showing <form:input as input type only.
and at background spring is linking to the element because of <form:input>

Comment: @Ankit So now i want to know how to create <form:input, so that spring will be aware the input element.

Comment: @Subratnayak.: You just want it to be spring aware for form submit or for some other reason as well?

Comment: @Ankit i just want to spring should accept the value given in the textbox and pass in to java methods.

Comment: @Subratnayak.: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the html equivalent of `<form:input` similarly create that in your javascript. Append that code in your page using javascript. The binding is done based on name, so it will work.

Make sure that you are appending code within the `<form` tag.

Comment: The equivalent of<form:input is <input.
The binding of html and spring is made by the "path" attribute.where as there is no attribute "Path" in <input> element

Comment: @Subratnayak. path == name, cssClass == class

Comment: Another alternative is to use something like jQuery to clone the relevant DOM.  Either way, adding to the DOM dynamically or cloning and adding, you will have to "fix" the path/name attribute, as it will most likely be an array or map of some sorts, and will most likely have some index/key that has to be properly updated to allow multiple values to be passed across.